# Batch optimizing PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, command-line, adobe

I need to make PDF Files of version 1.6 or 1.7 compatible with PDF 1.4.

I have Adobe Acrobat Professional X so I can do this with Action Wizzard but I need to do it programmatically (Command line or C# program)

I've tried with Adobe SDK but with no success (I can't choose the version of the output)

Anyone knows a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C#, use the Acrobat SDK JSO object to send some JavaScript to Acrobat that will run the preflight profile "Compatible with Acrobat 5". That will give you a PDF 1.4 file.

The documentation to run preflight on a document is located here...
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FDoc_methods.htm%23TOC_preflightbc-79&rhtocid=_6_1_8_23_1_78

Comment: I've achieved what I wanted by using the Javascript SDK indeed. With the SaveAs() method. I'll check your way, but the SaveAs seems to works fine. Thanks for your time!